# Android textDirection anyRtl not working for English text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml

I need an `EditText` box that shows the entered text (English) from right to left.

So if the user enters the word "him" on the keyboard, the `EditText` should show the following - first "h" then "ih" and finally "mih".

I thought `android:textDirection="anyRtl"` would achieve the same. I'm on API level 22.

But it doesn't seem to be working. This is my `EditText` code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:fontFamily="@font/digital"
    android:minEms="7"
    android:maxLength="10"
    />
```

Any reason why `rtl` or `anyRtl` isn't working. Am I misunderstanding how it works? How can I achieve my required use-case?

Comment: Is this for arabic ?

Comment: Hi Indra, it's for English. I've edited the question.

Comment: Do you want to reverse the words [English] in EditText ?

Comment: @SirosBaghban hey so whatever he enters should be prepended to the EditText text instead of appended.

Answer (score 0):

Through Android document:

> If the text **contains** any strong right to left non-format character, determines that the direction is right to left, **falling back to left to right** if it finds none.

Your input 'him' is obviously an English word, which contains no RTL character.
In your case, I think that you may choose "rtl" or "locale".

Seeing: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextDirectionHeuristics.html